# AWS S3 CLI creating multiple directories when using mv command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to move S3 bucket files from one folder to an archive folder in the same S3 bucket and I am using mv command to do this. While moving I want to exclude the movement of files in the archive folder.

I am using the following command

```
aws s3 mv s3://mybucket/incoming/ s3://mybucket/incoming/archive/ --recursive --exclude incoming/archive/" --include "*.csv"
```

but this command is moving the files but also creating multiple hierarchical archive folder when running multiple times

so,

1. 1st run - files moved from `/mybucket/incoming/` to
   `/mybucket/incoming/archive/`
2. 2nd run - new files moved from
       `/mybucket/incoming/` to `/mybucket/incoming/archive/archive/`
3. 3rd run -
       new files moved from `/mybucket/incoming/` to
       `/mybucket/incoming/archive/archive/archive/`
4. 4th run - new files
       moved from `/mybucket/incoming/` to
       `/mybucket/incoming/archive/archive/archive/archive/`

Can someone suggest/advise what exactly I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
aws s3 mv s3://bucket/incoming/ s3://bucket/incoming/archive/ --recursive --include "*.csv" --exclude "archive/*"
```

The order of include/exclude is important, and the references are relative to the path given.